Canonical equation of the line
${f}_{\ x,y}(x,y) = a*(3x+2)$, if 0<y<x<2
Looking for E[Y|X=1].
I get ${f}_{x}(x) = 2 * a*(3x+2)$,
(integral from 0 to 2),
h(y) = ${f}_{\ x,y}(x,y)$ / ${f}_{\ x}(x)$ = 1/2
To calculate the expectation value, I take the integral over [0,2].
Is it worth taking the integral up to 1, since y<x under density conditions?
